# Application copied to a different folder

Tags: laravel-7

I had copied my app to a different folder at the same computer (I'm using XAMMP), I've copied the database  with a different name too, at the same computer of course, modified the database name at .env, pointing to the new created database. I've got a big page not fould message (localhost/app/login).

Seem that my routes are not working.

I updated composer, App key, cleared all caches with the same result.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just putting it on your production server?

Comment: Yes, 'cause I'm using it as a base for creating two different applications, so the platform is still my own computer. I will deploy it to the production server when I finish any of them and my server is a shared one, so I suppose is more similar, I don't have ssh access.

Comment: I am not sure I understand; in any case, my guess is copying the site locally, and then copying that to production, is going to be harder - or rather, have more room for error - than just copying to production. If you are worried about exposing it on production before it is ready, put it behind simple htpasswd protection, or restrict access by IP, etc.  Lastly, don't forget there are [some installation steps](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation) required, beyond just copying files (eg setting directory permissions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are those installation steps required, for a new instance of the same application? About the permissions, I have xammp mouted on a Windows machine, so I guess they are not required.

Comment: Think about it. Installation - eg setting directory permissions - is required so that the web server can save the compiled versions of your views that Laravel creates, save sessions, write logs, etc.  If you don't do those things ... the app can't run.  So, installation is required if you want your app to work.

Comment: Ok, if I copy, import database and change configuration files, everithing with different names, should it be enough to run? That's what my common sense tells me, 'cause then I have to trace a different error.

Comment: I created some new routes, the problem seem to be the routes are not being used.